# AWS-EC2 Cannot connect to instance after reboot

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am facing `"init: Caught abort, core dumped"` error. My previous session was abnormally,  I can't use `chown` command anymore so I decided to reboot instance. After that I am not able to connect to my instance such as: FTP, SSH, HTTP,...

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Below is the debug information:
*Security Group/Inbound rules:*

```
SSH TCP 22 0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule TCP 6379 0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule TCP 20 - 21 0.0.0.0/0
MYSQL/Aurora TCP 3306 0.0.0.0/0
```

*System log*

```
[    0.542891] system 00:0a: [io  0x10c0-0x1141] has been reserved
[    0.546055] system 00:0a: [io  0xb044-0xb047] has been reserved
[    0.562153] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 11 devices
[    0.564613] ACPI: bus type PNP unregistered
[    0.572377] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.575233] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.579056] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.582540] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
[    0.586028] TCP: reno registered
[    0.588038] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.591141] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.594521] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.597119] pci 0000:00:00.0: Limiting direct PCI/PCI transfers
[    0.600918] pci 0000:00:01.0: PIIX3: Enabling Passive Release
[    0.604369] pci 0000:00:01.0: Activating ISA DMA hang workarounds
[    0.607967] Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
[    0.718203] Freeing initrd memory: 7568K (ffff880037128000 - ffff88003788c000)
[    0.722384] microcode: CPU0 sig=0x306f2, pf=0x1, revision=0x25
[    0.725593] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.00 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
[    0.730349] Scanning for low memory corruption every 60 seconds
[    0.733871] Initialise system trusted keyring
[    0.736471] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
[    0.739493] type=2000 audit(1465401459.804:1): initialized
[    0.764309] HugeTLB registered 2 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.768478] zbud: loaded
[    0.770334] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
[    0.772689] Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.776375] fuse init (API version 7.22)
[    0.778891] msgmni has been set to 1979
[    0.781208] Key type big_key registered
[    0.783615] Key type asymmetric registered
[    0.786105] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    0.789020] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 252)
[    0.793062] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.795340] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
[    0.798232] io scheduler cfq registered
[    0.800522] pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5
[    0.803515] pciehp: PCI Express Hot Plug Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    0.807047] ipmi message handler version 39.2
[    0.809587] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input0
[    0.813836] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[    0.816069] input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSLPBN:00/input/input1
[    0.820266] ACPI: Sleep Button [SLPF]
[    0.822513] GHES: HEST is not enabled!
[    0.825051] xen:grant_table: Grant tables using version 1 layout
[    0.828290] Grant table initialized
[    0.830431] Cannot get hvm parameter CONSOLE_EVTCHN (18): -22!
[    0.833531] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 32 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    0.862542] 00:09: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    0.867617] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
[    0.870829] brd: module loaded
[    0.873228] loop: module loaded
[    0.890155] scsi0 : ata_piix
[    0.892133] scsi1 : ata_piix
[    0.894276] ata1: PATA max MWDMA2 cmd 0x1f0 ctl 0x3f6 bmdma 0xc100 irq 14
[    0.898888] ata2: PATA max MWDMA2 cmd 0x170 ctl 0x376 bmdma 0xc108 irq 15
[    0.905590] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    0.910411] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[    0.914535] tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
[    0.918333] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[    0.921391] xen_netfront: Initialising Xen virtual ethernet driver
[    0.928165] blkfront: xvda: barrier or flush: disabled; persistent grants: disabled; indirect descriptors: enabled;
[    0.937276] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    0.941871] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    0.949195] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[    0.953430] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    0.962458] ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
[    0.965396] ohci-platform: OHCI generic platform driver
[    0.971784] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.976112]  xvda: xvda1
[    0.979714] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K,PNP0f13:PS2M] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
[    0.991661] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    0.997716] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[    1.003550] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.011100] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2
[    1.020401] rtc_cmos 00:04: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
[    1.027103] rtc_cmos 00:04: alarms up to one day, 114 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
[    1.035508] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    1.040913] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.27.0-ioctl (2013-10-30) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    1.051822] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    1.058681] TCP: cubic registered
[    1.063519] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    1.069695] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.073197] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    1.077170] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    1.081258] Loaded X.509 cert 'Magrathea: Glacier signing key: eb178a95d58f38dba12bad4c52c4257e44d6ab5b'
[    1.087311] registered taskstats version 1
[    1.091799] Key type trusted registered
[    1.096566] Key type encrypted registered
[    1.100313] AppArmor: AppArmor sha1 policy hashing enabled
[    1.103846] IMA: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass!
[    1.107882] xenbus_probe_frontend: Device with no driver: device/vfb/0
[    1.111994] regulator-dummy: disabling
[    1.114532]   Magic number: 4:633:992
[    1.117234] rtc_cmos 00:04: setting system clock to 2016-06-08 15:57:40 UTC (1465401460)
[    1.122820] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
[    1.126485] EDD information not available.
[    1.130561] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1336K (ffffffff81d20000 - ffffffff81e6e000)
[    1.135758] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 12288k
[    1.139873] Freeing unused kernel memory: 764K (ffff880001741000 - ffff880001800000)
[    1.146004] Freeing unused kernel memory: 680K (ffff880001b56000 - ffff880001c00000)
Loading, please wait...
[    1.164161] systemd-udevd[127]: starting version 204
[    1.201493] FDC 0 is a S82078B
[    1.720163] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2400.001 MHz
[    2.231369] input: ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input4
Begin: Loading essential drivers ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done.
Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount ... done.
[    2.768599] EXT4-fs (xvda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ... done.
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... done.
[    2.935267] random: init urandom read with 50 bits of entropy available
[    2.952875] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    2.962946] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    2.969045] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    2.977031] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    2.980696] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    2.990614] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    2.996620] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.007815] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.014989] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.024113] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.029120] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.039051] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.048685] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.056654] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.061955] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.070040] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.074703] init: Error while reading from descriptor: Bad file descriptor
[    3.084192] init: Error while reading from descriptor: Bad file descriptor
[    3.093818] init: hostname main process (232) terminated with status 6
[    3.104508] init: plymouth-ready (startup) main process (234) terminated with status 6
[    3.116246] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (236) terminated with status 6
[    3.121501] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[    3.125653] init: hwclock main process (238) terminated with status 6
[    3.129604] init: startpar-bridge (hostname--started) main process (240) terminated with status 6
[    3.135151] init: startpar-bridge (plymouth-ready-startup-started) main process (242) terminated with status 6
[    3.141536] init: startpar-bridge (plymouth-upstart-bridge--started) main process (244) terminated with status 6
[    3.148329] init: startpar-bridge (hwclock--started) main process (246) terminated with status 6
[    3.155105] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.160461] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.164776] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.170217] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.174056] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.179238] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.182793] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.187965] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.191571] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.196793] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.200371] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.205572] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.208767] init: Error while reading from descriptor: Bad file descriptor
[    3.213044] init: mountall main process (248) terminated with status 6
[    3.217088] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (250) terminated with status 6
[    3.222039] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[    3.226206] init: startpar-bridge (hostname--stopped) main process (252) terminated with status 6
[    3.231580] init: startpar-bridge (plymouth-ready-startup-stopped) main process (254) terminated with status 6
[    3.237557] init: startpar-bridge (hwclock--stopped) main process (256) terminated with status 6
[    3.242929] init: startpar-bridge (plymouth-upstart-bridge--started) main process (258) terminated with status 6
[    3.249824] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.254931] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.260290] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.265684] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.269716] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.274919] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.278016] init: mountall post-stop process (260) terminated with status 6
[    3.282172] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (262) terminated with status 6
[    3.287058] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[    3.291077] init: startpar-bridge (plymouth-upstart-bridge--started) main process (264) terminated with status 6
[    3.298045] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.303209] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.306718] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.311799] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.315426] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.320534] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.324123] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.329210] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.332798] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.338020] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.346092] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.354719] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.357845] init: Error while reading from descriptor: Bad file descriptor
[    3.363173] init: startpar-bridge (mountall--stopped) main process (266) terminated with status 6
[    3.368653] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (268) terminated with status 6
[    3.373544] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[    3.377674] init: console-setup main process (270) terminated with status 6
[    3.381866] init: plymouth-stop pre-start process (272) terminated with status 6
[    3.386388] init: startpar-bridge (plymouth-upstart-bridge--started) main process (274) terminated with status 6
[    3.391654] init: startpar-bridge (console-setup--started) main process (276) terminated with status 6
[    3.397076] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.401471] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.404960] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.409384] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.412704] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.417322] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.420578] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.425259] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.428457] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.433261] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.436836] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.442134] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.445087] init: Error while reading from descriptor: Bad file descriptor
[    3.448841] init: mountall-shell main process (278) terminated with status 6
[    3.454603] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (280) terminated with status 6
[    3.458953] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[    3.462361] init: startpar-bridge (mountall-shell--started) main process (282) terminated with status 6
[    3.467302] init: startpar-bridge (console-setup--stopped) main process (284) terminated with status 6
[    3.472558] init: startpar-bridge (plymouth-stop--stopped) main process (286) terminated with status 6
[    3.477480] init: startpar-bridge (plymouth-upstart-bridge--started) main process (288) terminated with status 6
[    3.483404] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.488006] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.491530] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.496242] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.499631] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.504472] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.507167] init: Error while reading from descriptor: Bad file descriptor
[    3.510698] init: mountall-shell post-stop process (290) terminated with status 6
[    3.514794] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (292) terminated with status 6
[    3.519126] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[    3.522557] init: startpar-bridge (plymouth-upstart-bridge--started) main process (294) terminated with status 6
[    3.528606] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.533055] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.536730] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.541202] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.544488] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.549003] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.551674] init: startpar-bridge (mountall-shell--stopped) main process (296) terminated with status 6
[    3.556728] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (298) terminated with status 6
[    3.561282] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[    3.564718] init: startpar-bridge (plymouth-upstart-bridge--started) main process (300) terminated with status 6
[    3.570904] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.575284] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.578682] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.583252] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.585978] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (302) terminated with status 6
[    3.590346] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[    3.593936] init: startpar-bridge (plymouth-upstart-bridge--started) main process (304) terminated with status 6
[    3.599965] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.604452] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.607744] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.612131] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.614808] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (306) terminated with status 6
[    3.619110] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[    3.622701] init: startpar-bridge (plymouth-upstart-bridge--started) main process (308) terminated with status 6
[    3.628533] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.632958] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.636221] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.640687] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.643362] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (310) terminated with status 6
[    3.647784] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[    3.651340] init: startpar-bridge (plymouth-upstart-bridge--started) main process (312) terminated with status 6
[    3.657232] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.661688] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.664970] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.669342] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.672046] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (314) terminated with status 6
[    3.676342] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge respawning too fast, stopped
[    3.679769] init: startpar-bridge (plymouth-upstart-bridge--started) main process (316) terminated with status 6
[    3.685787] init: error.c:219: Assertion failed in _nih_error_raise_system: errno > 0
[    3.690230] init: Caught abort, core dumped
[    3.692862] init: startpar-bridge (plymouth-upstart-bridge--stopped) main process (318) terminated with status 6
[   95.808134] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
```